# How to programmatically expand primeng treetable

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I want to expand `primeng treetoggler` dynamically. When I 
manually click on treetoggler icon it is expanding and collapsing but when I try to expand it from typescript code, it didn't worked. Node is not expanding.

In typescript I called click even of treetoggler.Actually click event is passing through the entire code nodeExpand but in UI, particular row is not expanded.

Even all rows have expanded property set to true.

How to resolve this issue.

Comment: I couldn't find anything documented in primeng public api. But there are `toggle` `expand` `collapse` methods in `UITreeNode`  component which i suppose might be used to achive what you want. Here: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/tree/tree.ts

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to study the [official documentation](https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/treetable).
Part: **Change Detection**.

Another [answer](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/5872) from developer PrimeNg.